# Blocking Plugin Css to load custom in template directory

Tags: plugins, themes, css

What is the most popular method to stop/block a plugin from loading their css styles ( located in the plugin directory) so that I can use the custom copy I made (located in my template directory).

I ask this because I have one css document ( complied using sass,scss and grunt) that a visitor of my website loads. I want to add the plugin css to that document ( and to use the sass variable functions).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dequeue a style, for do that you can use [wp_dequeue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) or [wp_deregister_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style)

To use both of them, first u need to find the **handler** of the style you want.

Go to the plugin's folder you wanna remove the css and search for wp_enqueue_style or the file name and locate the handler.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-font-awesome', plugins_url('my-plugin/font-awesome.css') );
```

and i need to deregister or dequeue it

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_fontawesome_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_fontawesome_deregister_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'my-plugin-font-awesome' );
}
```

or

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_fontawesome_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_fontawesome_deregister_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'my-plugin-font-awesome' );
}
```

OBS: the priority must be higher than the plugin's wp_enqueue_scripts()